# Difference between arrays and pointers in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am really confused in arrays and pointers.
Please tell me What is difference between following two codes?

```
int main()
{
    int i,*p;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        p[i]=i;
        printf("%d",p[i]);
    }
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,p[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        p[i]=i;
        printf("%d",p[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @devnull What's it got to do with fairness?  It's just desirable - if you don't see it happening it's probably because the other viewers don't have a good answer bookmarked, or one's harder to find... just start it off with your own close vote....

Comment: I was pretty sure it's a duplicate when I saw the title, then hesitated at its description, yet there *must be* similar posts lying around with the same root cause. Yet I realize that it may be hard for a novice user to relate them to his problem. Therefore I don't vote down for this.

Comment: Hey plz tell me about flags and votes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First one results in [undefined behaviour](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/07/what-is-undefined-behavior.html).
For not having [UB](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/07/what-is-undefined-behavior.html) you need to allocate memory using either `malloc` or `calloc`.
Allocating memory will store the data in heap. After you done with your task , you need to `free` the allocated memory also.

Second one do not result in [UB](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/07/what-is-undefined-behavior.html). it stores the array data in stack and not on heap.
Memory is automatically freed from stack once the scope is over.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vijay actually i am new to c can you please tell me where can i find more information about how data is stored in heap or stack?

Answer (score 4):

In first `p` points to garbage location (not-allocated), and I'm pretty sure that in the way you are using it will generate a segmentation fault. You should allocate memory first, before using it, like:

```
p = malloc(5 * sizeof(int))
```

Second is allocated on stack and have the lifetime of the scope it is declared in.

Comment: Not necessarily segmentation fault, its undefined behaviour, his code may run, or may be crash with core dump. its undefined read Vijay's answer.

Comment: thanks @Pavel.lazar and Grijesh Chauhan can u please tell me more about segmentation fault?

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar why not read this: [Segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) ,read OS sends a signal to process and kill